# Nested span not picking up onClick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got a nested SPAN inside of another span that is not being picked up my jQuery - and I wanted to both find a way to make this work, and find out why it isn't working.

Basically, I have a span, which is actually a popover (bootstrap)
It's meant to be for confirmation of deleting a record.

Here's what I've got:

```
                <span 
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" 
                data-placement="top" 
                data-toggle="popover" 
                style="cursor:pointer" 
                title="Confirm" 
                data-content="<center><span style='cursor:pointer' id='deleteRecordSpan' class='remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove'><p style='display:none'><?=$row['uniqueID'];?></p></span></center>"
                ></span>
```

The SPAN inside of data-content is suppose to be a 2nd button (the button that actually hooks into jQuery to do my ajax commands) - and the button shows up and has the proper information associated with it, but when clicked, it never fires the jQuery event (As per firebug)

My js:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.remove').click(function() {
                var input = input = $(this).text()
                $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                    data: {
                        uniqueid: input,
                    },
                    type: 'POST', // GET or POST from the form
                    url: './ajax/deleteRecord.php', // the file to call from the form
                    success: function(response) { // on success..
                       show10();
                       allToday();
                   }
               });
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I think bootstrap has stopPropagation on their elements which prevents stuff underneath catching the click events. I think if you can bypass that you are golden. Or just move it up by using z-index and absolute.

Comment: @Chris I don't want to break any other features of my site just because of this - how can I move it up by z-index and absolute?

Comment: Why is your HTML in a `data-content` attribute, is that a typo, or is it supposed to be like that? If it's the latter, the markup is inserted by Bootstrap dynamically, and you need a delegated event handler -> `$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {...`

Comment: @adeneo it's part of Bootstraps 'popover' elements. Your delegated code works, I've never had to do that before.
Could you please make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the HTML is in a `data-content` attribute, Bootstrap inserts the markup dynamically, and you'll need a delegated event handler

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
        var input = $(this).text()
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                uniqueid: input,
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url: './ajax/deleteRecord.php', form
            success: function(response) {
               show10();
               allToday();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the `<p>` tag inside your span tag. Try to put your uniqueId as an data attribute of your span tag like this:

```
<center><span style='cursor:pointer' id='deleteRecordSpan' class='remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove' data-unique='<?=$row['uniqueID'];?>'></span></center>
```

Then your unique id will not be shown. And you can use your id in this way:

```
var input = $(this).data('unique');
```